# Custom registration form in django is not working correctly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The form fills in successfully even when a short numeric password is entered. I want the form not to be able to set short passwords only consisting of numbers.

```
#forms.py
class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Адрес электронной почты')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль повторно',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='Введите тот же самый пароль ещё раз для проверки')
    captcha = CaptchaField(label='Введите текст с картинки ', error_messages={'invalid': 'Неправильный текст'}, generator='captcha.helpers.math_challenge')

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError(
                'Введённые пароли не совпадают', code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = AdvUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'photo', 'description', 'captcha')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my form to this and everything started working correctly:

```
#forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Адрес электронной почты')

    class Meta:
        model = AdvUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'photo', 'description')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some password validations that django has provided. You can use them by adding them in `settings.py`:

```py
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 9,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

With these, password should at least has 9 length, and can't be just numeric

You can read about it more in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation

Also, if these aren't enough, you can make your own custom password validation. Read about it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator

Comment: I have these validators in settings, but they don't work in this form. I do not understand why?

Comment: Try changing  `clean_password(self)` to  `clean_password1(self)` @ilsurealism

Comment: Changed, but now an KeyError at /accounts/register/
'password1' appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra condition in your `clean_password1(self)` function to achieve this-

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

        --------------------------------------------

        def clean_password1(self):
            password=self.cleaned_data['password1']
            if len(password1)==0:
                raise ValidationError("Please enter a password")
            if len(password1)<8:
                raise ValidationError("password is too short!")
            if password1.isdigit():
                raise ValidationError('Your password should contain letters!')
            return password1
```